# Network limits to calling HTTP APIs?

Tags: multithreading, api, networking, network-programming, httprequest

Here's a hypothetical situation:

say I'm iterating in a single thread though a data set and making HTTP calls for each entry to some API on the web. Assuming the API uses no throttling, should I be expecting non-degrading performance from the calls? As in, will I start seeing failures accumulating at some point as I loop through the entries (for various reasons, maybe network related) or should everything be predictably fine?

Now, let's say I start using a thread pool for the above iteration. I imagine each thread will open an outbound port to the destination. What determines the maximum # of threads I can use to call the same API? How will performance or success rate degrade with increasing # of threads?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is still relevant but anyway:
In scenario a) I wouldn't expect any negative impact since you will have at any time only one request/response running. So the throughput time should only depend on how fast your server can handle the requests.

In scenario b) one limitation will be the maximum number of connections (tcp or udp) your client (ie the OS) tcan have open at any given time. The same of course also applies to the other side. If this number is not a limiting factor I would expect the server to go down with a certain amount of requests. You'll create your own DoS attack ;-)